# SQL Server 2016 Restore From URL

Tags: sql-server, backup, storage, restore

I'm having some trouble restoring databases in SQL Server Management Studio which have been backed up to Microsoft Azure. I have been able to create the maintenance plans which successfully create the backups using a credential I have set up. The credential has been set up pointing to my container with the storage account key as the secret.

When I come to restore from a URL I fall short at various points depending on how I go about it.

If I right click on databases on the object explorer and restore from there, I change my source from disk to URL, enter the container & key and it seems to connect up. However I cannot see my .bak files in the pop up file selector. If I then go in to Azure and create a container access policy to read & write, I can see them in SSMS however the backup fails still (error stating no backups were selected). In any case I'd prefer not to leave the access policy open to the public.

If I right click on the actual database that I backed up to URL and select restore, the restore window opens and seems to instantly find the backups in my Azure container. However the backup still fails.

However, if I do all of this manually using T-SQL and specifically state my credential (restore database [dbname] from [url] with credential = 'credname') it works. This is a workaround I can use however it seems like a long-winded way of doing something that should be available through the UI in SQL Server 2016.

It seems to me like there's a problem with my credential; at least there's a problem with SSMS using my credential when I use the wizards. However I haven't seen an opportunity at any point to actually use my credential in the wizard. I've seen mention of a shared access signature however I don't know what this is or how to create one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks